# Asp.net : How can I ( send a selected date on calnder to another page as a text ) using (httppost / Request.Form )

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, send

Can I do this using (httppost or Request.Form ):

I have two pages (WebForm)
**page1** has a calender and a button.

When the user click on the button after he selected a date from the calender

directly will go to **page2** by (PostBackurl)

and on **page2** the user will see the selected date as a text.

Comment: Why not use Request.Querystring? have the button redirect to the other page with the date added to the url as a querystring variable. Then just get the querystring variable and set the label's text value to it.

Comment: because my teacher asked me to do it with the (httppost / Request.Form )

Comment: Create a form and set it's action to page2 and the method to post. Then in the other page use Request.Form["fieldname"] to get the data from the other page. Easiest way is to use a standard HTML form, but the asp.net form has a PostBackUrl attribute that you can designate the URL to perform the postback to.